# Inner Join in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT FirstName from tbl_User INNER JOIN tbl_Organisation  
on tbl_user.tbl_organisation_OrganisationID=tbl_Organisation.OrganisationID      
  WHERE tbl_organisation_OrganisationID = '23'
```

I want to get a column(OrgName) from tbl_Organisation. how can I do that with the above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT tbl_User.FirstName, tbl_Organisation.OrgName from tbl_User INNER JOIN tbl_Organisation  
on tbl_user.tbl_organisation_OrganisationID=tbl_Organisation.OrganisationID      
  WHERE tbl_organisation_OrganisationID = '23'
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply with :

```
SELECT tu.FirstName, tor.OrgName from tbl_User tu INNER JOIN tbl_Organisation tor
on tbl_user.tbl_organisation_OrganisationID=tbl_Organisation.OrganisationID      
WHERE tbl_organisation_OrganisationID = '23'
```

Comment: Isn't "to" a reserved keyword in SQLServer ? I'm not sure, it may work like this, but I would call the tbl_Organisation "tor", just to be sure.

Comment: Indeed that's an error of my part :) I edited my post. Anyway, as far as he works with MySQL, to could work.

Comment: I deleted my -1 vote, I misread, I thought it was SQLServer, anyway thanks for the edit. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT FirstName,tbl_organisation.OrgName
FROM tbl_User 
INNER JOIN tbl_Organisation ON tbl_user.tbl_organisation_OrganisationID=tbl_Organisation.OrganisationID  
WHERE tbl_organisation_OrganisationID = '23'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FirstName, tbl_Organisation.OrgName from tbl_User INNER JOIN tbl_Organisation  
on tbl_user.tbl_organisation_OrganisationID=tbl_Organisation.OrganisationID      
 WHERE tbl_organisation_OrganisationID = '23'
```